# How can I format string for float number on Delphi correctly?

Tags: string, delphi, floating-point, format

I need to call `Format` function to return the following strings:

```
1.0 -> "1 or 1.0"
1.01 - > "1.01"
1.001 - > "1.001"
1.0000001 -> "1.0000001"
```

It it possible? The standard format string `%0:f` returns only two digits after the point (for example, `"1.01"`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`%g` general format string](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.Format):

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

begin
  Writeln(Format('%g', [1.0]));
  Writeln(Format('%g', [1.01]));
  Writeln(Format('%g', [1.001]));
  Writeln(Format('%g', [1.0000001]));
end.
```

**Output**

```
1
1.01
1.001
1.0000001
```

Comment: Thanks, but why it doesn't work for the number `90.12345678901234`? It returns `90.1234567890124`.

Comment: That number is at the limit of precision for a double precision value. Do you appreciate the issue of representability for floating point data types? For instance the only number in the question that is exactly representable is `1.0`. Do you appreciate that floating point values have finite precision?

Comment: I also need to represent `number(16,14)` using this format string... I'll use `%0.14f` for it.

Comment: I don't really understand that comment.

Comment: The result string is used to represent `number(16,14)`. I've checked it and it works. The correct format condition is `%0:.14f`.

Comment: May be stupid question, but what is `number(16,14)`?

Comment: @Rudy - it's a database data type - see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT313

Comment: @MattAllwood: Thanks. I don't "do" databases, so I had never seen it before.