# How to format a big number into string for display in Delphi

Tags: delphi, number-formatting

I have a double type big number, say `1111111111111110000000000000.000.` How to format it to string for display in Delphi?

I've tried `FloatToStr` and `FormatFloat`, but I receive the Scientific Notation which is not what I want.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24562127/how-can-i-format-string-for-float-number-on-delphi-correctly

Comment: @IgnazioC i don't think so, it's totally different, i'm trying to format a big number

Comment: Have you already checked this? [Formatting numbers beyond 18 digits without E-notation](http://codeverge.com/embarcadero.delphi.general/formatting-numbers-beyond-18-digit/1055263)

Comment: Use scientific or engineering notation. Nobody wants to count all those digits.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Sadly that i got a requirement to show the whole digits in string format

Comment: Whoever is behind that requirement doesn't understand what they are doing. Oh well. I guess that eventually when the users who do understand maths start giving feedback things might change!

Comment: double typically has only about 15-17 digits of precision. Read these [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [System.Str](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Str) conversion works:

```
var
  d: Double;
  s: String;
begin
  d := 1111111111111110000000000000.000;
  Str(d:0:3,s);
  WriteLn(s);
end;
```

Outputs: 1111111111111109950000000000.000

Note: double precision has not the precision to exactly hold the digits you are trying to input.

Normally in that case you would not show all digits, since this can give the impression that they all are accurate. This is why the scientific notation is prefered.

Comment: What about format with f or n specifiers? Do they revert to scientific when the abs value gets large?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, Format with f,g or n specifier autmatically changes to exponential presentation, regardless of precision specifiers or not.

Comment: Thank you. Would it have been too much to have hoped the docs would have been able to tell me that? Sigh.

Comment: Thank you, and it helps me a lot